# Kivy Python 2.7 - Put a layout inside of another layout

Tags: python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have been looking into this question for a while, and I cannot seem to find the solution anywhere. I want to put a table inside of this page I have in my app, the page is a FloatLayout and I was wondering if it was possible to put a table inside of the FloatLayout.

Comment: You can add every widget in a layout then yes you can

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to put a table inside of the FloatLayout. In the following example, we have a GridLayout inside a FloatLayout. As for a table, you might want to use [RecycleView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.recycleview.html).

## Example

### main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout


class RootWidget(FloatLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    title = "GridLayout Inside FloatLayout Demo"

    def build(self):
        return RootWidget()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestApp().run()
```

### test.kv

```
#:kivy 1.10.0

<RootWidget>:
    size: 300, 300
    GridLayout:
        cols: 3
        row_force_default: True
        row_default_height: 40
        Button:
            text: "Row 1 Col 1"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 100
        Label:
            text: "Row 1 Col 2"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 100
        Button:
            text: "Row 1 Col 3"
        Button:
            text: "Row 2 Col 1"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 100
        Label:
            text: "Row 2 Col 2"
            size_hint_x: None
            width: 100
        Button:
            text: "Row 2 Col 3"
```

### Output

[image: Figure 1 - App Startup]